# Get to exact line with javascript error in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

If I have an error in my javascript code, and I run the page on google chrome, I click wrench icon > tools > JavaScript console, and it shows me (in red) the exact line in my js causing the error.

On IE, I click the yellow "!" icon in the status bar, and it gives me an error message, along with a line #. While this is often helpful, many times it is not: (1) the line # in my source file often differs from the line # that IE gives me; (2) in complex systems, there might be several js files involved, and the IE message doesn't tell me which one.

So my question is: are there any options that get IE8 to show me the exact js line with the error -- without having to install anything?

I know that IE8 has a built-in javascript console, and I recall using it, but I don't remember figuring out how to achieve with it the goal I've stated in this post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe Firebug Lite could help you out? http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: @polarblau Firebug only works on Firefox. There is a version for Chrome called "Firebug Lite", but the best is for Firefox. Another option is to use http://www.firebugger.com/, but I think that are better choices to do the same.

Comment: @Fran Verona: Please read my comment once more and preferable more than two words of it. The link included btw. points to a page which states the following: "Compatible with all major browsers: IE6+, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using "Developing Tools" on IE8? I've been using for a while and works well. You can find it on "Tools" menu or pressing F12 key.

If you go to "Script" tab, you can find console, breakpoints, local variables, etc that could be useful to you.