# IE AJAX Cross-Browser Issue

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I have the following AJAX function:

```
function ajaxDesignerBrandInfo()
{
    var D = wrapFormValues('#designer-brand-form');
    var recursiveEncoded = $.param(D);  
    /*
    $.post("/api/designer_brand/", { data : recursiveEncoded }, function(data) 
    {
        var results = $.parseJSON(data);
        window.location = "/register/designer-product/"; 
    });*/

    $.ajax( { type: "POST", 
              url: "/api/designer_brand/", 
              data : { data : recursiveEncoded },
              success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "/register/designer-product/";
            },0);
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ){
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError); }
        });

    return false;   

}
```

And the corresponding form

```
<form id="designer-brand-form" name="form" method="post" action="" onSubmit="ajaxDesignerBrandInfo(); return false;"> 
....
</form>
```

The submission works great on Chrome, Safari and FireFox, moving me to

/register/designer-product/

Correctly, but in IE9, the submissions seems to

1. Never make it to the server
2. clear the form and redirect back to the current page i am on (in which this form exists).

I can confirm via FireFox there are no javascript errors causing this to fail. And sometimes it actually works, but I cannot seem to always reproduce this error in the same way

Someone Please explain WTF is going on?

Thanks

Comment: I added the SetTimeout because I read that it would fix my problem, but it did not infact fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that IE is silently throwing a Javascript error.  Just because Firefox doesn't throw a JS error one doesn't mean that IE doesn't.  Check for JS errors in IE (see [this link](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/4009) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203322/get-to-exact-line-with-javascript-error-in-ie8/5203972#5203972)).  Find the error and you'll find the solution.

Also, try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is a standalone Windows tool that acts as a proxy server and will tell you EXACTLY what your AJAX traffic looks like.

Your specific problem may be the `console.log` call.  That is a Firebug thing (that Chrome supports).  IE does not, I think, unless you take steps to add it.  See: [What happened to console.log in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Comment: Correct, the console.log will toss an error unless you have the dev console open specifically (F12) in IE

Comment: @Joseph Misiti: Do you have the Developer Tools console open sometimes?  That would do it.  ;)

Comment: looks like it was console.log